# Does clearcase merge duplicate the file?

Tags: merge, clearcase

In case there is a .txt file on X branch and a merge is done to main branch does clearcase save only the delta in it's database without duplicate the file ?

What if I'm doing a merge to a binary file ( which clearcase can't merge ) does it actually duplicate the entire file, so one copy on the X branch and another on main branch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In case there is a `.txt` file on X branch and a merge is done to main branch does clearcase save only the delta in it's database without duplicate the file ?

Yes, only the delta, within a single source data container in the vob.
See "[About type managers and size limitations](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21127322)".

> What if I'm doing a merge to a binary file ( which clearcase can't merge ) does it actually duplicate the entire file, so one copy on the X branch and another on main branch ?

Then the type manager will likely be compressed_file. They cannot be merged
See "[Handling binary files in ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21123371)".

> ClearCase can only merge text files; therefore a different strategy must be deployed in order to manage change related to binary content.
>
> In order to effectively manage binary files in ClearCase, new element types must be defined to handle these file types. The following options are available:
>
> - Configure element type to be never considered for merging. ClearCase will not attempt to merge elements with a never merge type. These elements will be left unchanged during a deliver or rebase operation and you will not be prompted to merge them.
> - Available in ClearCase 7.0 and later: Configure element type to **copy**. For elements with a copy type, ClearCase will, in a merge, replace the target version with the source version without user interaction. See technote 1240740 for more information.

Comment: Hi, I understand it can't be merged by clearcase but still I will be able to "merge" to the main branch and check in right ? so in that case the file is duplicated ?

Comment: @Epligam yes, it will be duplicated.

Comment: @VonC - the "About type managers and size limitations" Technote above is dated.  The [type_manager Knowledge Center topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/type_manager.htm) and [Size limits on VOB elements Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21408364) are probably more apropos.